# How can I manually write mapping for jooq without generator?

Tags: java, mapping, jooq

I want to write custom mapping for my database without code generation. How can I do it?
I need mapping only for two tables and several columns. Do I really need a mapping generator?

Comment: What do you want to map? Columns? Tables? Schemas? Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. I want to create Java pojo classes and map them on insert/select query. Are there any guides to do that? I don't need smth complex